# IntelliJ and Dart: restart daemon/dartvm

Tags: dart, intellij-idea, intellij-13

I'm doing Dart FFI development in IntelliJ to create bindings to a native library. While trying to get the bindings right, I seem to be messing up some internal memory of this library. After making corrections to my code, the library is still in an inconsistent state due to my earlier errors. This is because the updated code is run inside the same instance of the DartVM as earlier: IntelliJ doesn't restart it, it reuses it. The only way to get back to a consistent state is to **restart** IntelliJ, which is quite annoying.

Is there a way from inside IntelliJ to only restart the DartVM used to run my program? I've not been able to find any way...

Comment: Sounds kinda strange. On my IntelliJ installation it starts a new `dart.exe` process when I want to run my program. Are you sure your process is stopped before starting a new one?

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear which Dart VM you want to restart.

There's only one long-living Dart VM, it's Dart Analysis Server, the tool from the Dart SDK that is responsible for code highlighting, completion, and other code insight features in the IDE editor. To restart it click the corresponding button in the Dart Analysis tool window, or open Find Action and search for 'Restart Dart Analysis Server'.

Speaking of running your application, IDE doesn't reuse any running VM. Which run configuration type do you use to start your app: Dart Command Line App or Dart Web App (see Run -> Edit Configurations)? Both have the 'Stop' button in the Run tool window in case you application doesn't terminate normally itself.

More details about the problem (probably with screenshots) will help us to give a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for this information. It seems I need to look elsewhere for the cause of my instability issues in my FFI bindings.

What I observed was:
1. Run test program, see it crash (usually segfault) on "Step X"
2. Implement a code correction to (hopefully) fix this
3. Run test program, see it crash "Step X - 2", e.g. *before* the original crash

I assumed I had put my native library in some invalid state, and that the programs DartVM wasn't being restarted. However I have now run my test program multiple times from the command line, and I see the same behavior, so nothing IntelliJ related